# How to use Oracle Update Select Statement?

Tags: oracle, converters

**TABLE A**

```
ITEM BASE_WT BASE_AMT
AAA 50 500
BBB 100 6000
```

**TABLE B**

```
ITEM OUTDAY WT AMT
AAA 20140105 10 100
BBB 20140106 10 600
AAA 20140107 10 100
```

**TABLE A RESULT**

```
AAA 30 300
BBB 90 5400
```

**MSSQL QUERY**

```
UPDATE A SET
BASE_WT  = BASE_WT - X.WT
BASE_AMT  = BASE_AMT - X.AMT
FROM A,
(
    SELECT ITEM , SUM(B.WT) WT, SUM(B.AMT) AMT 
    FROM B
    WHERE OUTDAY BETWEEN '20140105' AND '20140107'
    GROUP BY ITEM
) X
WHERE A.ITEM = X.ITEM
```

Comment: please describe what's working wrong

Comment: see this answer by myself on different ways [a]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20905876/oracle-database-how-to-update-selected-columns/20906038#20906038

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE A
SET (BASE_WT, BASE_AMT)
  = (SELECT A.BASE_WT - SUM(B.WT), A.BASE_AMT - SUM(B.AMT)
     FROM B
     WHERE B.OUTDAY BETWEEN '20140105' AND '20140107'
      AND B.ITEM = A.ITEM)
WHERE A.ITEM IN (SELECT ITEM FROM B WHERE OUTDAY BETWEEN '20140105' AND '20140107');
```

The outer WHERE condition avoid to reset (to NULL) the records in A that don't have a corresponding ITEM in your subquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
update a
  set (base_wt, base_amt) = (
     select 
       a.base_wt  - x.wt,
       a.base_amt - x.amt
     from (
      select 
        b.item, 
        sum(b.wt )  wt, 
        sum(b.amt) amt 
      from 
        b
      where 
        outday between date '2014-01-05' and date '2014-01-07'
      group by
        item
     ) x
     where
       x.item = a.item
  )
```

See also [this sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b087f/3).